# Elegant method to convert UInt8 array of variable length to Integers

Tags: swift, data-conversion

Suppose I have one `UInt8` array of variable length and the lengths can be of 1, 2, 4 and 8 and it can be either signed or unsigned. Target is to convert this array to corresponding Integer.

Following is my best try but it looks ugly as there is apparent code duplication. Is there any elegant method to solve this problem? Any suggestions are appreciated.

```swift
func fromByteArray<T>(_ value: [UInt8], _: T.Type) -> T {
    return value.withUnsafeBytes { $0.baseAddress!.load(as: T.self) }
}

func convert(_ hexList[UInt8], _ isSigned: Bool) -> Any {
    if is_signed {
            switch hexList.count {
            case 1: return Int(fromByteArray(hexList) as Int8)
            case 2: return Int(fromByteArray(hexList) as Int16)
            case 4: return Int(fromByteArray(hexList) as Int32)
            case 8: return Int(fromByteArray(hexList) as Int64)
            default: return 0
            }
    } else {
            switch hexList.count {
            case 1: return UInt(fromByteArray(hexList) as UInt8)
            case 2: return UInt(fromByteArray(hexList) as UInt16)
            case 4: return UInt(fromByteArray(hexList) as UInt32)
            case 8: return UInt(fromByteArray(hexList) as UInt64)
            default: return 0
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: `[UInt8]` is always fishy when I see it, are you sure that shouldn't be `Data` or an `UnsafeRawPointer`? And returning either an `Int` or `UInt` under the umbrella of `Any` is also suspicious. Could you provide more details on what the calling context is like, where you're getting this data from, and what you're trying to do with it?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Actually I'm trying to do some raw parsing: like  unsigned `0xFF 0x00` -> `UInt16(255)` (yes it is little endian)

Comment: What *exactly* is the type/value of your input?

Comment: Hex string array like this: "`0xFF 0x00`" or like "`FF 00`". i'll convert it to a UInt8 array. Seems that SO is not friendly to newbies...

Comment: What makes you say that?

Comment: Never mind. I'm here to ask for help or suggestions not to make friends or enemies.

Comment: Will the input `"0xFF 0x00"` always be treated as unsigned? Should it always be `-256 as UInt` and not `65280 as Int`?

Comment: I'm literally asking you for details about your problem so that I can help you ...

Comment: `Will the input "0xFF 0x00" always be treated as unsigned? ` Not exactly, there is a rule(or mapping) indicating whether the current decoded array is signed or not(that's why there is a parameter `isSigned` in my original method)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233473/discussion-between-alexander-and-codingnow).